# How to include Android.Support.v4 in Xamarin Forms (iOS)?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using Visual Studio For Mac. My Xamarin Forms project is quite large and contains many content pages. Some of them will be only used in android project and some of them only used in iOS project. There is no problem when I compile the project into android. However, when I want to compile the project into iOS, it seems like did not accept anything related to android. Please refer to the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRGwb.png). There is no way I can include the android specialised reference and compile into iOS project. So, any idea to deal with this? Maybe there is a way to force build the iOS project no matter what? The error from the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRGwb.png) is from the page that will be only used in android. So what I can do for now is delete the page when I want to compile as iOS and recreate the page when I want to used it for android. But there are plenty of them, it is too heavy for me to do this every time. Please help.

Comment: The question is why do you have a platform-specific piece of code in your PCL/SCL, does that not break the whole logic of Platform independent libraries?

Comment: That is because some of the features are only for android like toast widget.

Comment: So would it not make sense to have it in your native code and using dependency services? i.e. if you are following the .Net Standard approach! If you are following the approach of the shared project then things would be different!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call platform specific APIs at the .NET standard libraries that are used to host Xamarin.Forms code by default.

Basically you have those options:
1) using shared project instead of library and using conditional compiling (easier but it is now not available as the option when creating the project)
2) using dependency injection.